# Connect to MySQL from javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, mysql, servlets

I am making a small page where I can keep track of my hours I work. I have a form that look like this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Working Hours</title>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../dataExchange" method="POST">
        Day Hours:  <input type="text" name="Day_hours"><br>
        Day Minutes:    <input type="text" name="Day_minutes"><br>
        Allday Hours:   <input type="text" name="Allday_hours"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"><br><br><br>
    </form>
    <form>
         <input id="datepicker" />
    </form>
    <form>
        <input id="datepicker2" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Here I also have a javascript, that is a calendar, where there is a "from" date "to" date.
My connection to my database goes through a servlet, that looks like this:

```
package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/dataExchange")
public class dataExchange extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String Date = req.getParameter("Date");
        String Name = req.getParameter("Name");
        String Address = req.getParameter("Address");
        String Allday_hours = req.getParameter("Allday_hours");
        String Day_hours = req.getParameter("Day_hours");
        String Day_minutes = req.getParameter("Day_minutes");
        String Km_to_address = req.getParameter("Km_to_address");
        String Time_to_address = req.getParameter("Time_to_address");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Workdata VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, Date);
            pst.setString(2, Name);
            pst.setString(3, Address);
            pst.setString(5, Day_hours);
            pst.setString(6, Day_minutes);
            pst.setString(4, Allday_hours);
            pst.setString(7, Km_to_address);
            pst.setString(8,  Time_to_address);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

        try {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I get my javascript calendar to get the information from my database? Can I connect from the javascript -> servlet -> MySQL database, or do I have to do something completely else?

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use a servlet that returns something. It can be anything: JSON, XML, text, whatever. You can call the servlet with AJAX and process the results in javascript. Or you can use a regular HTML `<form>` element like in your example above.

It is hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what you want.

If you mean the example above, you are not calling any methods of your `PrintWriter out` (except when getting an exception). You might also think about the content-type (now you are using `text/html`), perhaps JSON would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So the first thing I have to found out is how to use AJAX to call the javascript calendar function? I have tried to make something. I don't know if I am on the right track?

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   });
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
 });

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was perhaps a bit incomplete (now edited). You don't actually _need_ AJAX, you can just use a regular form. In that case, the resulting HTML (that you write to your PrintWriter) is sent to the user when he submits the form. I suggest that you get that part working first and only after that add a nice javascript calendar component.

Comment: Also, in your example you have 2 <form>:s. You should combine them so that when you press "Submit", the datepicker inputs are also sent to your servlet.